# Trying to send input from HTML form to DB using Python Flask, SQalchemy and SQlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

Hello I'm trying to send data from a html form into a sqlite database using Flask/SQAlchemy and sqlite. But when I want to test it, I get the following error: werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'Datum'

But when i look at Datum in my form and in my python file they should be correct? what am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
{% block body %}

<form action="{{ url_for('my_form') }}" method="POST">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Gasten registratie</h1>
        <p>Vul dit formulier in om te registreren</p>
        <hr>

        <label for="First-Name"><b>Voornaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="First-Name" placeholder="Vul hier uw voornaam in" name="Voornaam" required>

        <label for="Last-Name"><b>Achternaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="Last-Name" placeholder="Vul hier uw achternaam in" name="Achternaam" required>


        <label for="Company-name"><b>Bedrijfsnaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="Company-name" placeholder="Vul hier uw bedrijfsnaam in" name="Bedrijfsnaam" required>


        <label for="Date"><b>Datum</b></label>
        <input type="date" id="Date" placeholder="Selecteer de Datum" name="date" required/>
        <hr>


        <p>In het kader van onze ISAE certificering registreren wij uw gegevens.</p>
        <p>Wij verwerken uw gegevens volgends de regels van het AVG.</p>
        <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Registreren</button>
    </div>


</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from datetime import datetime


app = Flask(__name__) 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///guest.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class gast(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    voornaam = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    achternaam = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    bedrijfsnaam = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    datum = db.Column(db.Date)
    date_created = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
       return '<gast %r>' % self.voornaam


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/my_form', methods=['POST'])
def my_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        guest_vnaam = request.form['Voornaam']
        guest_anaam = request.form['Achternaam']
        guest_cnaam = request.form['Bedrijfsnaam']
        guest_datum = request.form['Datum']

        safe_vnaam = gast(voornaam=guest_vnaam)
        safe_anaam = gast(achternaam=guest_anaam)
        safe_cnaam = gast(bedrijfsnaam=guest_cnaam)
        safe_datum = gast(datum=guest_datum)

        try:
            db.session.add(safe_vnaam, safe_anaam, safe_cnaam, safe_datum)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'Er ging iets fout met het opslaan van uw gegevens'

    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date input in your html has a different name to your request.form.

change html input to:

`<input type="date" id="Date" placeholder="Selecteer de Datum" name="Datum" required />`